# AM-GM-HM on expression with parameters?

Tags: inequality

This question, which I believe is easier to answer, is related to my previous question: [Finding a value that makes an expression negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857565/finding-a-value-that-makes-an-expression-negative)

I am persistent - and need some ideas to help me prove something.

How can I show that:

$$W^2X-A(AW-X)^3<\frac{(AW-X)^4}{C}$$

where $$A,C,W,X>0$$

and $$AW>X?$$

Should I proceed by adding $A(AW-X)^3$ to both sides, and then applying AM-GM-HM? Or what other inequalities would be useful here? I'm new to Holder's, Jensen's, etc.

If you'd like, I have made the above expression into:

$$P-QR^3<\frac{R^4}{C}$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If $W=10, A=1/5, X=1,C=10$...

Comment: I tried many times and several ways, cannot!! please check

Comment: @mwomath The inequality is false.

Comment: @chubakueno You are right. Would you mind if I scrap this question and start a new one, one with more context and details? Thanks.

Comment: I think not, because radically editing the question would be more counter productive than starting a new one :)

Comment: @chubakueno Ok. I have started this new question then: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858089/inequality-involving-fractions-and-several-variables

Comment: Uhmm... there is something I don't understand. Is your question ill -posed, or it was right? If it is the second, you may answer yourself to close the thread.

Comment: @chubakueno I believe this AM-GM-HM on expression with parameters question was ill-posed...