# Inequality involving fractions and several variables

Tags: inequality, matlab

Based on my previous two questions (that failed), I am trying once more.

What are some simplified conditions for which:

$$W\bigg(A-\frac{X}{W}\bigg)^3\bigg[X-AW-\frac{AY}{N}(B+D)-\frac{AZ}{N}(C+D+E+F+G)\bigg]+\frac{X}{N}\bigg[Y(A+H)(B+D)+AZ(C+D+E+F+G)\bigg]<0$$

**WHERE:**

All of the letters are positive parameters (not constants) and:

$1.$ $$A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H < N \implies \frac{A}{N},\frac{B}{N},\frac{C}{N},\frac{D}{N},\frac{E}{N},\frac{F}{N},\frac{G}{N},\frac{H}{N} <1 $$

$2.$ $AW>X$

Is this problem tractable by hand, or do I have to use Maple/Matlab to simplify my expression somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $C$, $E$, $F$, and $G$ only ever appear in the combination $C+E+F+G$, so the first manual reduction is $C+E+F+G \rightarrow C'$, eliminating ~$1/3$ of the parameters.  Multiply through by $N W^2$ to eliminate denominators.  The second summand is entirely positive, so collapse it to, say, $V$ (now $H$ is gone too).  Having Mathematica (9.0) attack the resulting expression (and ignoring the implicit relationship between $V$ and $A,B,C',D,H,W,X,Y,\text{ and }Z$):
$$V-(A W-X)^3 (A (Y (B+d)+Z (C'+D)+N W)-N X)<0$$
yields a solution set composed of 96 parts.  (We're lucky.  It's not so hard to construct something about as complicated with over 1000 distinct solution components.)  An easy one:
$$0<A, 0<B<A/4, 4A \leq C', C'/4 < D, D < N, 0 < V, \{\zeta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \mid A^4 N \zeta^4 - V = 0\}_2 < W, \\ 0 < X \leq \{ \zeta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \mid \zeta^4-4AW\zeta^3+6A^2W^2\zeta^2-4A^3W^3\zeta+A^4W^4 -V/N = 0\}_1, 0 < Y,  \text{ and } 0 < Z$$
where I've used the nonstandard notation $\{\text{variable} \mid \text{polynomial}=0\}_n$ to mean the $n^\text{th}$ element in the ordered list of roots of the polynomial, in a specific (complicated to describe) order.  Every component has at least one of these polynomial roots in it.  (Scanning suggests two or three of these root-findings per component, in general.)

Enforcing the implicit relationship between $V$ and $A,B,C',D,H,W,X,Y,\text{ and }Z$ and also the relationship between $C'$ and $C,E,F, \text{ and } H$ won't improve the situation at all.

What kind of conditions were you hoping for?

Comment: Great effort. I had no idea the problem was so complex. I was hoping for some simpler conditions that could be interpreted to make sense...

Comment: @Anonymous: Are there any sort of "natural ranges" for the parameters?  These might lie in only a handful of the solution components...  Is there a solution or an asymptotic set of values that comes from your system?  We could try to find which component it lives in.

Comment: The only other constraint I can think of is that $N>A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H$, while everything else is just a parameter with no specified numeric range because I am looking through the problem with an "analytical lens".

Comment: I can work on this later, as I have moved on to another problem that I have. Could you take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858336/finding-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-sparse-matrix?noredirect=1#comment1770751_858336?