# Finding the largest eigenvalue of a sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I would like to find the largest eigenvalue of a sparse matrix by hand- this is part of analyzing a mathematical model for infectious diseases. The nonzero entries are very complicated - hence Maple took 6 minutes and 670MB of memory to find the eigenvalues.

Is there some general way (block matrices?) to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
J_{1,1} & J_{1,2} & J_{1,3} & J_{1,4} & J_{1,5} & J_{1,6} & J_{1,7} & J_{1,8} & J_{1,9} & J_{1,10} & J_{1,11} & J_{1,12} \\
0 & J_{2,2} & 0 & J_{2,4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
J_{3,1} & J_{3,2} & J_{3,3} & J_{3,4} & J_{3,5} & J_{3,6} & J_{3,7} & J_{3,8} & J_{3,9} & J_{3,10} & J_{3,11} & J_{3,12} \\
0 & J_{4,2} & 0 & J_{4,4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & J_{5,2} & 0 & 0 & J_{5,5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{6,6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{7,6} & J_{7,7} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{8,7} & J_{8,8} & J_{8,9} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{9,5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{9,10} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{10,6} & 0 & 0 & J_{10,9} & J_{10,10} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & J_{11,2} & 0 & J_{11,4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{11,10} & J_{11,11} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & J_{12,9} & 0 & J_{12,11} & J_{12,12} \\
\end{pmatrix}

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any control on the coefficients at all? And do you need an actual result or just a bound (e.g. a criterion for all the eigenvalues being negative)? Because otherwise, this matrix looks sufficiently generic that its characteristic polynomial is probably not solvable by radicals.

Comment: Row reduction won't help you anyway, it changes the eigenvalues. (Unless you meant symbolic row reduction to find $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)$, which is probably a better idea than cofactor expansion.)

Comment: @Ian Right on! I actually just need a bound (need to show that all eigenvalues are negative) under a certain condition. Besides row reduction (which sounds great, but I am not sure how to do it on Maple), any suggestions? (By the way, I finally obtained the exact eigenvalues by Maple, but I need to factor, simplify, and analyze them.)

Comment: So you want a condition on the $J_{i,j}$ such that all the eigenvalues are negative, then? Is a sufficient condition enough, or does it need to be necessary too?

Comment: I am not sure. Let's go with sufficient for now.

Comment: @Ian The problem is: I have found that one of the eigenvalues is DEFINITELY positive...

Comment: Based on your recent sequence of questions, it's time for you to give up on work "by hand" and learn a power tool.  You mention Maple, which should be fine for the questions you've been asking, although you may still get results that are rather complicated.

Comment: @EricTowers trudat